# Wxpython sound on text enter event

Tags: python, widget, wxpython

My question is a short one, however I was unsuccessful at finding the answer.

I am developing a wxpython project, where a method in the frame class is called when enter is pressed in a textctrl box. This works fine, however, there is a sound played when I press enter like a "dling" voice. I don't want this is my program. Is this removable ? or even better, replacable ?

Here is the relevant lines of the code about the problem.

```
self.send_box = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, -1, "", style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER)
self.send_box.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT_ENTER, self.enter_message)

    def enter_message(self, event):

        message = self.send_box.GetValue()
        self.send_box.SetValue("")
        print message
        event.Skip()
```

I am using Windows 10 64-bit OS if it helps.

Answer (score 3):

Just experienced the same problem. Although the question ist quite old, the answer may be helpful to anyone, who has the same problem.

Apparently, the sound is produced by the windows event handler when event.Skip() is called. If the handling of the ENTER button is finished, it is not necessary to call Skip() to invoke the windows event handler, see

https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.TextCtrl.html

because the ENTER will then either be "processed internally by the control or used to activate the default button of the dialog", which is typically not what you want.

If event.Skip() is not called, windows will not produce a sound.

Comment: if event and event.EventType != wx.EVT_TEXT_ENTER.typeId:
 event.Skip()

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that somewhere on your operating system, there is an option for turning on/off button and window sounds or event sounds.
Sorry, I can't tell you where it is on Windows, I use Linux.
It has nothing to do with wxpython.